# I changed the value of a token between 2 requests How is it possible?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

For a course about Spring boot security I wanted to demonstrate that the token was the best security because it isn't possible to change it. But it seems to be wrong, I managed to change a token between two requests !

First an example :

Token after login :

```
{
"id": 4,
"email": "jean.bon@monserveur.fr",
"password": "",
"username": "jean.bon",
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqZWFuLmJvbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0MzM4MDE1NSwiZXhwIjoxNjQzNDY2NTU1fQ.JUSTGCfWS9MrbBzkyEboaxHyZcBVwzC_TAH8LRx76wJmKZ9drF1cz51EWfKs9rd4GfxqwpE33-_5e0soylfA6w",
"roles": [
    "USER"
]
```

}

Result of the request employee/employee with this token :

[{"id":1,"name":"KING","job":{"id":1,"jobname":"President"},"managerId":null,"hiredate":"1981-11-17","salary":5000.00,"department":{"id":1,"dname":"Accounting","location":"NEW YORK"}},{"id":2,"name":"JONES","job":{"id":2,"jobname":"Manager"},"managerId":1,"hiredate":"1981-04-02","salary":3000.00,"department":{"id":1,"dname":"Accounting","location":"NEW YORK"}},...

Token modified : the last sign (w) replaced by x :

```
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqZWFuLmJvbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0MzM4MDE1NSwiZXhwIjoxNjQzNDY2NTU1fQ.JUSTGCfWS9MrbBzkyEboaxHyZcBVwzC_TAH8LRx76wJmKZ9drF1cz51EWfKs9rd4GfxqwpE33-_5e0soylfA6x",
```

Result of the request employee/employee :

[{"id":1,"name":"KING","job":{"id":1,"jobname":"President"},"managerId":null,"hiredate":"1981-11-17","salary":5000.00,"department":{"id":1,"dname":"Accounting","location":"NEW YORK"}},{"id":2,"name":"JONES","job":{"id":2,"jobname":"Manager"},"managerId":1,"hiredate":"1981-04-02","salary":3000.00,"department":{"id":1,"dname":"Accounting","location":"NEW YORK"}},...

If I replace the w by a sign before w, for example by a, it  doesn't work :
401 Unauthorized 11 ms 404 B

The token is generated by Spring boot security
The key
key= AzertyuiopQsdfgjklmWxcvbn1234567890!=
Expiration :
expiration= 86400000

Token generated by :

```
public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
    UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    JwtBuilder jwtBuilder = Jwts.builder();
    jwtBuilder.setSubject((userDetailsImpl.getUsername()));
    jwtBuilder.setIssuedAt(new Date());
    jwtBuilder.setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + expiration));
    jwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key);
    String token = jwtBuilder.compact();
    return token;
}
```

Token validated by :

```
public boolean validateToken(String token) {
    Boolean ret = false;
    try {
        JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser();
        jwtParser.setSigningKey(key);
        jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token);
        ret= true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Username extracted by :

```
public String getUserNameFromToken(String token) {
    JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser();
    jwtParser.setSigningKey(key);
    Jws<Claims> jws = jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token);
    Claims claims = jws.getBody();
    String userName = claims.getSubject();
    return userName;
}
```

Comment: I changed the library (https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) but I have the same problem ! Does any body has an explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's related to base64 encoding scheme. For example, if you take the "modified" Base64 encoded string, and then decode and re-encode it, you end up with the expected value.Slightly ugly test code to follow:

```java
String stringKey = "JUSTGCfWS9MrbBzkyEboaxHyZcBVwzC_TAH8LRx76wJmKZ9drF1cz51EWfKs9rd4GfxqwpE33-_5e0soylfA6x";
byte[] bytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(stringKey);
System.out.println("Original Key: " + stringKey);
String stringKey2 = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
byte[] bytes2 = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(stringKey2);
System.out.println("Re-encoded:   " + stringKey2);

assertThat(bytes, is(bytes2));
```

This test passes and outputs the following (the '=' are just padding):

```
Original Key: JUSTGCfWS9MrbBzkyEboaxHyZcBVwzC_TAH8LRx76wJmKZ9drF1cz51EWfKs9rd4GfxqwpE33-_5e0soylfA6x
Re-encoded:   JUSTGCfWS9MrbBzkyEboaxHyZcBVwzC_TAH8LRx76wJmKZ9drF1cz51EWfKs9rd4GfxqwpE33-_5e0soylfA6w==
```

You can get similar results in this test if you change the last letter to `h`:

```
Original Key: JUSTGCfWS9MrbBzkyEboaxHyZcBVwzC_TAH8LRx76wJmKZ9drF1cz51EWfKs9rd4GfxqwpE33-_5e0soylfA6h
Re-encoded:   JUSTGCfWS9MrbBzkyEboaxHyZcBVwzC_TAH8LRx76wJmKZ9drF1cz51EWfKs9rd4GfxqwpE33-_5e0soylfA6g==
```

TL;DR The signature decodes to the same original bytes (so the JWT is still valid)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but a (perhaps) last (but not least) question. Why in my example can I change the w by x or y or z, but not by v or u or v ?

Comment: Look at the ASCII encoding of these characters, and take a look at how the message padding works for Base64 Encodeing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64